# Instagram Hashtag Search reached limit when it hasn't

Tags: python, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

when I operate [IG Hashtag Search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag-search#reading) it show error below

```
{'error': {'message': '(#4) Application request limit reached', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'is_transient': True, 'code': 4,
```

But when I check [recently_searched_hashtags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/recently_searched_hashtags) it shows that I only retrieved 5 hashtag.

What is going on and how to solve the issue?